# How do I make a field autofocus?

Tags: javascript, focus

I need this field to be focused when the user opens the page. I don't know if it changes anything but it's inside a modal window I load from a PHP file.

Is there an easy way to do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

JavaScript autofocusers (as given in the other answers here) will work but can be annoying for some users. For example, if you focus a different field while a page is still loading, the JavaScript may "help" you by moving the focus and making you type in the wrong field. [This question](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/2861/2530) on ux.stackexchange.com enumerates some more drawbacks.

To prevent this, HTML5 has introduced an [`autofocus` attribute](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/association-of-controls-and-forms.html#autofocusing-a-form-control) for form elements that means the behaviour will be consistently implemented by the browser itself, and can be turned off for users that find it irritating. Of course, this isn't supported by all browsers yet. For more info, see the section on [autofocus fields](http://diveintohtml5.info/forms.html#autofocus) in Mark Pilgrim's excellent [Dive Into HTML5](http://diveintohtml5.info/) book.

Comment: @Dancrumb Yep, just added link to [related question on ui.stackexchange.com](http://ui.stackexchange.com/q/2861/2530) which has more discussion

Comment: Thanks I added "autofocus" and I'll later read it all so that it works on all browsers. Thanks

Answer (score 17):

Using JavaScript, you can achieve this:

```
document.onload = function() {  
  document.getElementById("question-box-0").focus();
}
```

Comment: I couldn't make it work also, it's a modal window that loads from a PHP file. Can that have anything to do? I added the script just above the form and it didn't work. Thanks

Comment: You'll need to add that script to exist within the `<head>` tag of the file the form is on. Surround it in `<script type="text/javascript"></script>` tags.

Comment: JS loaded with ajax or similar frameworks wont work. To execute JS functions they need to be loaded in <head> just like @MichaelIrigoyen stated

Answer (score 2):

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
document.onload = function() {
 document.getElementById('question-box-0').focus();
};
</script>
</head>
<body>
...
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It didn't work, it's a modal window that loads from a PHP file. Can that have anything to do? I added the script just above the form and it didn't work. Thanks

Comment: Try to set the script in the <head> tag like my example shows. This is to ensure that the document.onload event handler is set before the event actually occurs.